# Optimize MLT elasticsearch query

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I want to apply `more like this` query, so I use this(python wrapper for elasticsearch):

```
{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this": {
            "fields": ["title", "content"],
            "docs": [
                {
                    "_index": "kavosh",
                    "_type": "articles",
                    "_id": str(news_id)
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 1,
}
```

but I have many timeout. so i decided to reduce range of mlt checking to one week. (Is it effective?) for example adding this:

```
    {
        "range": {
            "publication_date": {
                "lte": now,
                "gte": now - 1week
            }
        }
    }
```

How can apply this filter to MLT query and do you have any suggestion to optimize query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query:

```
{
"query": {
  "filtered": {
     "query": {
        "more_like_this": {
           "fields": [
              "title",
              "content"
           ],
           "docs": [
              {
                 "_index": "kavosh",
                 "_type": "articles",
                 "_id": str(news_id)
              }
           ]
        }
     },
     "filter": {
        "range": {
           "publication_date": {
              "lte": "now",
              "gte": "now - 1week"
           }
        }
     }
  }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.